# Using "xbindkeys" and "xdotool" to set fullscreen on firefox 60.1.0esr

Tags: centos, x11, kiosk-mode, firefox-quantum

My intention is to know if there is a way to set firefox-60.1.0 in fullscreen mode once it is opened to act as a kiosk, but using the **Xbindkeys** and **Xdotool** programs.

*Note: I've already performed some tests, that's why I changed a little bit the scope of the original question.*

XBindKeys uses a configuration file **.xbindkeysrc** for binding keys.

For example, I edited this file to set firefox in fullscreen mode by pressing `shift + f` keys combination. Then, this action activates the xdotool command to send the `F11` key to the browser only if firefox is already opened:

```
# set firefox to fullscreen if opened
"xdotool search --classname navigator key F11"
  shift + f
```

The problem is that it only works on **firefox 52.8.0esr** but my target is **firefox 60.1.0esr** and later versions.

So now, I´m wondering 2 things:

- Will "xbindkeys" and "xdotool" programs be compatible with firefox-60.1.0 and later versions?.
- Are there any Xclients replacement that are compatible with firefox-60.1.0 and later versions?.

Some other Xclients I have found are (but not tested so far):

- xvkbd
- xkb
- xmodmap

..also other alternatives to xdotool such as autokey and more from these posts:

https://alternativeto.net/software/xdotool/?platform=linux

Note: I´m using centos for testing this.

Thanks for your help!

BR

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you, any keys are allowed before Firefox starts AND then only keys you want are allowed?

Use xbindkeys to start a shell script that:

1. remaps with `xmodmap` any keys you wish to surpress into something harmless
2. starts `firefox` as a background process
3. uses `xdotool` to send an F11 key to the firefox window
4. then waits for `firefox` to complete
   and finally
5. uses xmodmap to restore the original keybindings.

Comment: Yeah, but you'll notice my method doesn't rely on you hiting some other key to send it, it just does it on it's own. You will probably need a `sleep $n` in there between steps two and three to wait for the firefox window to open, n=2 or so is probably good, depends on your system. (Or you could loop until xdotool can find the window.)